# Where does $k^{n-1}$ come from in this solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction, determinant

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixfw9.png)

I started this problem by plugging $\mathrm{det}(kA)$ into the first row cofactor expansion formula we're given, and I got stuck at approximately the second step. This solution manual pulled the $k$ out and put it to the power of $n-1$. Is this because you're using every row except the last/first one when you multiply $k$? If so, why?

Comment: If $A$ is $n \times n$ and you do a cofactor expansion you are writing $\det(kA)$ in terms of determinants of $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrices.  For me I would prefer to use $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$ (not too hard to validate in general, but maybe that is not where the textbook is) with $B = kI$ (determinants of diagonal matrices are easy to compute!).

Comment: Why is det(kA) in terms of (n-1)x(n-1)? It's probably a trivial answer I just got a bit lost there. I don't get how the problem made the jump fro det(kA) to k^(n-1) det(kA)

Comment: In the cofactor expansion you march across a row and apply row entries to determinants of matrices one size smaller, where the inductive hypothesis (because those matrices take the form $k \times (\text{a cofactor matrix of $A$}$) is that the determinant is $k^{n-1} \times (\text{determinant of the smaller matrix})$.

Comment: Ahhh okay that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

In (c), the proof of $\det(kA)=k^n\det(A)$ of an $n\times n$ matrix uses induction, so it is natural to step from  $\det(kA)=k^{n-1}\det(A)$ for an $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrix using the inductive hypothesis.

The remaining $k$ is a factor in the additional row.

Comment: Ah okay. Did that proof shown above skip a ton of steps? Or is that a valid way to do it?

Comment: @SultanHall The steps seem reasonable to me if you understand know $A_{1j}$ is an element of the matrix and $\det(A^{1j})$ is the corresponding cofactor